# creating a Cron Job to delete rows in mysql database when they are early than today

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have tried many times now but i just dont seem to be able to crack it!

I have set up a cron job on cpanel (was every minute for testing) with the command set at

```
/php cronjobcommand.php
```

In my cronjobcommand file i have the following code

```
<?php//conenct to your DB
$db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxx', $db_conn);


$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'data' 
  WHERE 'offerends' < CURDATE()}
                               LIMIT 1", $db_conn);
    //might want to check here to see if the query executed successfully

?>
```

I want it to delete any rows that have a date of less than today at midnight each night. what am I doing wrong? The job seems to find my file fine, i get my email without errors, but no difference to database.

Thanks Jamie.

Comment: Does the query work in mysql? Why the Limit 1? What is the '}' character doing?

Comment: First of all: use mysqli or PDO since MySQL will be deceprated. Two questions about your query: why the } and limit 1?

Comment: `... or trigger_error(mysql_error());` (just for the test).

Answer (score 4):

Run this against your database using Adminer or PHPMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM 'data' WHERE 'offerends' < CURDATE() LIMIT 1
```

This will give you the matching rows, you can then debug using this query which might be easier.

You also seem to have a stray `}` in your DELETE query.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I managed to get it worked from your help! Love this place!